# Is there a way to know the type of bumper

Tags: honda, civic, bumper

[image]is there a way for me to be sure of the type of bumper installed on a civic 2009 ? Without having to unclip it to look around ? It was bought used and I'm unsure if it's the OEM PP bumper or fiberglass aftermarket.

There was a tag inside but I had no luck finding its meaning. That is why there is a spot without dirt in the picture below

[image: recent collision damage]

[image: interior of bumper]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Are you trying to figure out if the bumper is a real Honda bumper or an aftermarket replacement? Are you just asking about the bumper cover, or the entire thing? Your pics are so close up it's hard to tell exactly what we're looking at.

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for the replied, I can update a complete photo. What I am trying to understand is if the bumper is plastic (either oem or aftermarket) or fiberglass aftermarket. I have been told if the interior is smooth, the feel and the way it break can be used to tell plastic and fiberglass apart. I can't tell by myself

Comment: If you can flex the bumper at all, it's plastic. Fiberglass is stiff and inflexible. If you flex fiberglass, you break it.

Comment: So basically if I was able to flex the corner to some extend to take my photo and see the interior it's plastic. Fiberglass bumper are 100% rigid and can't be bent a little ?  I'm quite intrigued as to what the waves in the blue and black part in the interior are. I read that plastic interior are totally smooth and fiberglass have weaves. Thanks for your knowledge!

Comment: "A little" is subjective. I'm talking you can flex fiberglass mere millimeters. There is give, but no real flex. Besides, looks like a Honda Civic. They only ever used plastic bumper covers on them. In fact, I don't know of any modern day cars which use fiberglass other than the Corvette. There may be others, but it definitely isn't common place.

Comment: Just to add to what Paulster2 wrote, besides Corvette, there are a few other vehicles that use fiberglass, but no mass production vehicles like the Honda Civic use fiberglass.  That said, there are aftermarket parts available that use fiberglass.